# RxKotlin flattenAsObservable(): type mismatch with method reference

Tags: kotlin, rx-kotlin

I'm converting some Java code to Kotlin and I'm having some trouble with `flattenAsObservable()`

Here's what the code looked like in Java:

```
discogsInteractor.search(query)
    .map(RootSearchResponse::getSearchResults)
    .flattenAsObservable(searchResults -> searchResults)
    .take(12)
```

Here's what I have so far in Kotlin:

```
discogsInteractor.search(query)
    .map { RootSearchResponse::searchResults }
    .flattenAsObservable<SearchResult> { searchResults -> searchResults }
    .take(12)
```

It underlines the second `searchResults` and gives me the following error:

```
Required: (Mutable)Iterable<SearchResult!>!
Found: KProperty1<RootSearchResponse, List<SearchResult>>!
```

I can replace

```
.map { RootSearchResponse::searchResults }
```

with

```
.map { searchResponse -> searchResponse.searchResults }
```

and it will work. How do I correctly method reference? Or what's the reason that I can't in this instance?

**RootSearchResponse:**

```
data class RootSearchResponse(val pagination: Pagination,
                              @SerializedName("results") val searchResults: List<SearchResult>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RootSearchResponse::searchResults` is a method reference. Instead of passing this to the `map` function, by using `{}`, you're passing in a lambda that always returns this method reference.

Basically, you're mapping every incoming element to that method reference with your `map` operation, instead of applying that method to every element like you'd want to. So the incoming parameters of your `flattenAsObservable` method are always that same reference to the `searchResults` method, which is a `KProperty1`.

To apply the method that you're referencing to every element, you can pass the method reference in regular parentheses, like so:

```
.map(RootSearchResponse::searchResults)
```

---

For an additional simple example of what's happening with the lambda:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map { 2 }
```

This operation would map every element to `2`, and you'd end up with a list that only contains `2` five times. It's basically just shorthand for the following, just without an explicit parameter name:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map { x -> 2 }
```